# PID: how to deal with delay between controller and a process?

Tags: pid-controller, pll

In designing a digital pll, I'm facing a problema with a communication delay between the loop filter output and the frequency synthesizer (via SPI).
If I dont consider the communication delay the system suffer with a high overshoot, long stabilizing time or no synchonization at all.

Its a classical design: ref_in  --> phase_detector --> PID --> SPI_controler --> frequency_synth --> phase_detector

Any tips would be very appreciated.

Comment: Look into dead time compensation- the communication delay is essentially a dead time and, as you have found, will tend to negatively affect stability.

Comment: Thank you for the tip -- I´ll look into this matter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to incorporate the delay in your transfer function \$H(z)\$. If the delay is a multiple of the sampling period, then the delayed transfer function is simply
$$H(z) z^{-m}.$$

If the delay is not a multiple of the sampling period, you can do a couple of things. Firstly, it is probably a good approximation to select the closest multiple of the sampling period. Secondly, you can use the advanced z-transform, which is given by
$$F(z, m) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty f(Tk + m) z^{-k}.$$
If the delay \$m\$ is a constant, which it will be in your case, then the advanced z-transform has the same properties as the z-transform.

It is important to check the controllability matrix when you have a significant delay. It can render the system uncontrollable in certain situations.

Comment: Thank you for the clear information -- I´m considering your tip and, may be, a "smith predictor" as I have read on some papers.